# CSS not overriding bootstrap

Tags: css

I have a span tag with a class specified.  In my CSS I use that class to set "align:left" in order to override bootstap css of "align:center".  When I inspect the span tag, my override is checked as is the bootstrap css with a "align:center" crossed out.  But the text in the span is still centered.  If I uncheck the "align:center" style, it aligns left.  Why is bootstrap not being overridden?  I also tried using and ID instead of a class but for some reason the CSS didn't get picked up at all.  Here is some code:

```css
.bulletsLeft {
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

```html
 <span class="bulletsLeft">
   Some text!
 </span>
```

and

```css
#bulletsLeft {
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

```html
<span id="bulletsLeft">
  Some text!
</span>
```

Comment: Please upload a jsfiddle or pen for us to debug.

Comment: Did you make sure to call your custom CSS file after Bootstrap? Also, there's no need to use `!important` as long as the custom CSS is being loaded after Bootstrap and the selector has the same specificity as it does in Bootstrap.

Comment: Is there any space to align in? Make the span wider than the text and see if the align works. Give the class a `width` property.